# Get array textfield value read by javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

forexample, i have this code:

```
<input type="text" name="width[]">
<input type="text" name="width[]">
<input type="text" name="width[]">
<input type="text" name="width[]">
<input type="text" name="width[]">
<input type="text" name="width[]">
```

How can I read this value by javascript array. I could do that using php like this;

```
<?
    $values=$_POST['width'];
    foreach($values as $value){//each value}
?>
```

the javascript variable's each value should be accessible using loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByName('width[]');
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you use Jquery ..here's the Jquery method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name="width[]"]').each(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myForm = document.forms.id_of_form; 
var myControls = myForm.elements['width[]']; 
for (var i = 0; i < myControls.length; i++) { 
    var aControl = myControls[i]; 
}
```